# Parallel.For Termination vb.net

Tags: vb.net, parallel-processing, vb.net-2010

I have a service that scans network folders using a parallel.for method.

However recently I am finding if I stop the service then while windows says the service is stopped the process is still running in task manager. However it is at 0 cpu and the memory does not change. If I try and end the task (even a force in command prompt) it just says access denied and i have to reboot the server.

What would be the best way to make sure everything terminates?

I thought of adding a global Boolean that in the stop procedure it turns true and part of my parallel code will check for that and call s.stop.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, when your service is stopped, it needs to cancel all pending and running operations, then wait for those operation to actually finish.  Check out the MSDN reference for [Task Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx).

Comment: Sorry I forgot I posted this. I see that also works for parallel.foreach. Thank you